# Issue while deleting row using DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, delete-row

Following code does not delete a row from dataset and dont update the database....

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = cs;
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select *from RegisterInfoB", con);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adpt.Fill(ds, "RegisterTable");
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["FirstName"] == "praveen")
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                    }
                }
                ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

How to resolve this problem...How do I update my sql server database...by deleting a row from dataset..

Comment: do you strictly need `DataSet`? or `SqldataReader` is okay for you?

Comment: @Sandeep Kushwah.......Strictly Required to go with DataSet....

Comment: Are you getting any errors? tried Debugging line by line?

Comment: one error unable to cast to object to string but i trying to typecast....but its not working after typecasting....no error is showing

Comment: at line? which line?

Comment: if (dr["FirstName"] == "praveen")
here is a error....dr["FirstName"].ToString.......so i type cast it

Comment: okay got it. Give me  a sec

Comment: I have posted the code please check and comment there is any errors..

Comment: Having now dealt with three separate problems, I am very interested in knowing if this has been resolved.

Comment: @ Morpheus ........Problem is solved................

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET ... good to know the `SqlCommandBuilder` worked for you.  This may also help someone else if they have a similar question to yours in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = cs;
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from RegisterInfoB", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds, "RegisterTable");
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["FirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "praveen")
                {
                    dr.Delete();

                }
            }
            adpt.Update(ds);
```

Two Changes 
`1st: if (dr["FirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "praveen")` trimming the blank spaces in your db's `FirstName` Field.
`2nd :` use `adpt.Update(ds);` to update your DB.

Another Way to doing it:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = cs;
                string firstName= "praveen"; // this data will get from calling method
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from RegisterInfoB", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adpt.Fill(ds, "RegisterTable");
                string deleteQuery = string.Format("Delete from RegisterInfoB where FirstName = '{0}'", firstName);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, con);
                adpt.DeleteCommand = cmd;
                con.Open();
                adpt.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Similary, you can write query for `UpdateCommand` and `InsertCommand` to perform Update and Insert Respectively.

Comment: Exception is occur-Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'. but load button successfully fetch the RegisterTableInfoB from the database

Comment: @ sandeep Kushwah......Second method works but it directly delete a row from database not from dataset.....

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET : So you dont want to update DB? Only local changes?

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET : Could you please tell exactly what you need? What I have suggested in 2nd solution is to perform Delete operation using `DataSet`. I have also metioned how update and insert operation can be done using the DataSet.

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET : Could you please tell me what exception you are getting while using first approach?

Comment: In First method that you are suggested it fetches the databasetable in dataset successfully but when delete a record from the dataset it will not reflected in database ....

Comment: In second method you are perfroming deletion operation on RegisterInfoB table of database, (Direct interaction in database you are performing with the help of DataAdapter). I want first delete a record from the dataset and then this updation is reflected in the database. but you delete a record from the database table directly...your second approach not interacting the dataset......

Answer (score 0):

Find rows based on specific column value and delete:

```
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = ds.Tables["RegisterTable"].Select("FirstName = 'praveen'");
foundRows.Delete();
```

**EDIT**: Adding a DeleteCommand to the data adapter (based on example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx))

*Note: Need an `Id` field here instead of `FirstName`, but I don't know your table structure for `RegisterInfoB`.  Otherwise, we delete everyone named "praveen".*

```
// Create the DeleteCommand.
command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM RegisterInfoB WHERE FirstName = @FirstName", con);

// Add the parameters for the DeleteCommand.
parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NChar, 25, "FirstName");
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

// Assign the DeleteCommand to the adapter
adpt.DeleteCommand = command;
```

To update a database with a dataset using a data adapter:

```
try
{
    adpt.Update(ds.Tables["RegisterTable"]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Error during Update, add code to locate error, reconcile  
    // and try to update again.
}
```

Sources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x(v=vs.120).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: how i delete a particular row from a dataset?

Comment: I'll edit with a suggest, but maybe you only need to add `ToString()` to your existing code?

`if (dr["FirstName"].ToString() == "praveen")`

Comment: Hi @PraveenYadavCSPIET if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  If you want more assistance please post the error message and let us know where the error is occurring.

Comment: Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.......................InvalidOperationException is occured while updating the database

Comment: Answer has been edited to show what it means for the data adapter to have a DeleteCommand.

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET - Anywhere near a solution yet?

Comment: Yes i performed the CRUD operation on DataSet by using SqlCommandBuilder..........

Comment: I only recently found out about `SqlCommandBuilder` from another question on SO, but for that person they were not using only one single table which is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

hope that resolve the problem, 
Try it:

```
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        var selectQuery = "Select * from RegisterInfoB";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();        

        // you can use the builder to generate the DeleteCommand
        adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
        // or 
        // adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM RegisterInfoB WHERE Id= @Id", connection);

        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "RegisterInfoB");

        // you can use the foreach loop 

        foreach (DataRow current in dataSet.Tables["RegisterInfoB"].Rows)
        {
            if (current["FirstName"].ToString().ToLower() == "praveen")
            {
                current.Delete();
            }
        }

        // or the linq expression 

        // dataSet.Tables["RegisterInfoB"]
        //    .AsEnumerable()
        //    .Where(dr => dr["FirstName"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == "praveen")
        //    .ToList()
        //    .ForEach((dr)=> dr.Delete());

        var result = adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables["RegisterInfoB"]);
```

also you can add some events and put a breakpoint to see if the state is changing or if there is an error that prevent changes on the source:

```
        dataSet.Tables["RegisterInfoB"].RowDeleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var r = e.Row.RowState;
        };

        dataSet.Tables["RegisterInfoB"].RowDeleting += (s, e) =>
        {
            var r = e.Row.RowState;
        };
```