# How to perform a Insert , Update, Delete from a Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to perform a Insert , Update, Delete from a Dataset, Specifically from Dataset and then updating the database after CRUD operation on dataset.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue while deleting row using DataSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830618/issue-while-deleting-row-using-dataset)

Comment: @Sandeept First code falls with an exception and second method works but it directly interact with database.....not with dataset...

Answer (score 0):

If you have tables on the database this is what you do:

```
INSERT INTO [tblMGT247FeeAccruals] ([PortfolioID], [TransactionDate], [SettlementDate], [TransactionValue]) 
VALUES (@PortfolioID, @TransactionDate, @SettlementDate, @TransactionValue); SCOPE_IDENTITY())

UPDATE [tblMGT247FeeAccruals] 
SET [PortfolioID] = @PortfolioID, [TransactionDate] = @TransactionDate,   [SettlementDate] = @SettlementDate, [TransactionValue] = @TransactionValue 
WHERE AccruedFeeID = @AccruedFeeID

DELETE 
FROM tblMGT247FeeAccruals
Where AccruedFeeID = @AccruedFeeID
```